# Python: how to visualize plotly chart in a notebook

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to run a `plotly` chart as suggest [here](https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget/) but nothing appears on my notebook. How can I visualize it?

**Code:**

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
%pylab inline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interactive, HBox, VBox

f = go.FigureWidget()
py.init_notebook_mode()

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonmmease/plotly_ipywidget_notebooks/master/notebooks/data/cars/cars.csv')

f = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(y = df['City mpg'], x = df['City mpg'], mode = 'markers')])
scatter = f.data[0]
N = len(df)
scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df['City mpg'].max() - df['City mpg'].min())
scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df['City mpg'].max() - df['City mpg'].min())
scatter.marker.opacity = 0.5

def update_axes(xaxis, yaxis):
    scatter = f.data[0]
    scatter.x = df[xaxis]
    scatter.y = df[yaxis]
    with f.batch_update():
        f.layout.xaxis.title = xaxis
        f.layout.yaxis.title = yaxis
        scatter.x = scatter.x + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df[xaxis].max() - df[xaxis].min())
        scatter.y = scatter.y + np.random.rand(N)/10 *(df[yaxis].max() - df[yaxis].min())

axis_dropdowns = interactive(update_axes, yaxis = df.select_dtypes('int64').columns, xaxis = df.select_dtypes('int64').columns)

# Create a table FigureWidget that updates on selection from points in the scatter plot of f
t = go.FigureWidget([go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid'],
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
    cells=dict(values=[df[col] for col in ['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid']],
               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5))])

def selection_fn(trace,points,selector):
    t.data[0].cells.values = [df.loc[points.point_inds][col] for col in ['ID','Classification','Driveline','Hybrid']]

scatter.on_selection(selection_fn)

# Put everything together
VBox((HBox(axis_dropdowns.children),f,t))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: my problem is that nothing appears. Can I save it as html or visualize it on the notebook?

Comment: If I run on the notebook, the plot does not show up.

Comment: my code is there and my question is simple. How can I visualize the chart showed here https://plot.ly/python/figurewidget/ ?

Comment: @emax Your code snippet, *exactly* as it is, runs just fine on my end in a Jupyter Notebook and produces a scatter plot with two widgets. Both work perfectly. So *how* are your running your code? Directly in a Jupyter Notebook. Or through an IDE like Spyder or PyCharm? Jupyterlab perhaps? A description of your system with version information would be very helpful.

Comment: @vestland I am running it on my Jupyter Notebook but it does not produce the plot.

Comment: @emax And no error messages? Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @vestland I added the screenshot. Yes I don't get any error

Comment: Have you tried : py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True) ? and you are calling it twice one with connected and one without.. can you comment the one without and test?

Comment: @AnshulJindal great, thanks!

Comment: I will add that as answer then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

as mentioned [here](https://plot.ly/python/offline/).